# Can't access pgadmin4 from nginx-proxy-manager

Tags: docker, nginx, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have setup multiple containers on my server and I want to access them through a more friendly url; So I've also setup `nginx-proxy-manager`. Every other container is accessible except for `pgadmin4`.

Other containers like **Grafana** or **Prometheus** are accessible from the nginx-proxy-manager, but pgadmin4 can only be accessed by hitting the IP:PORT directly. By typing [pgadmin.keivanipchihagh.ir](https://pgadmin.keivanipchihagh.ir) I'll get: *Bad gateway Error code 502* (do visit the website for more info on the error)

My pgadmin4 `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:

  # pgadmin4
  pgadmin:
    container_name: ${PGDAMIN_CONTAINER_NAME:-pgadmin}
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.13
    restart: unless-stopped
    user: "$UID:$GID"

    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_PASSWORD}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'True'

    volumes:
       - ./pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin

    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"

    networks:
      - epd


networks:
  epd:
    external: true
```

Also my nginx-proxy-manager config (just like any other container I've setup already):
[image: nginx-proxy-manager config for pgadmin]

Any Ideas?

Comment: If you are accessing the pgadmin4 container from another contained on the `epd` network, you need to be using port 80, not port 5050. Port publishing doesn't impact container-to-container communication; that's only for exposing ports on your host.

Comment: @larsks, ahh I missed that, problem solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you stumble upon this and are out of ideas, try deactivating 'Cache Assets'.